MudBlazor ChipSet - selecting chips programmatically
I need to implement a "Select all" functionality whereby the user can select all chips via a button click, rather that clicking each item (which can be many!)
                            
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
           OnClick="(() => AllChips.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsSelected = true))">
    Select all media
</MudButton>
                            
<MudChipSet SelectedChips="@SelectedChips" 
            MultiSelection="true" 
            Filter="true">
     @foreach (var chip in AllChips)
     {
          <MudChip Text="@chip.Text" />
     }
</MudChipSet>

I've explored the IsSelected and Default properties of a MudChip to no avail. The tooltip I get is that those properties should not be set outside of their component.
Is this possible to achieve with MudChipSet?

Firstly, you need to bind the SelectedChips value. Your current code shows SelectedChips="@SelectedChips", however to make it two-way bindable, it should actually be @bind-SelectedChips="SelectedChips". Then you'd be able to update the bound value.
Updating the values becomes as simple as
    private void SelectAll()
    {
        SelectedChips = AllChips.ToArray();
    }

Here's a quick Try.MudBlazor example

One point though I think you should mention in your answer that OP needs to use @bind-SelectedChips not just SelectedChips

How would that work if you have a single chip? I'm creating a MudChip per object that I have (assigning only the "Text" property) and then stuff them in a list. Now I'm filtering one chip from that list and trying to set the matching chip to be selected, but it won't set it.
Demo here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOweEzaxfXjVrtFe

Could you create a new question an fully explain your scenario. If it's not the same select all functionality asked for by the OP it shouldn't be discussed here.

Just did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78426134/mudblazor-mudchipset-how-to-set-selected-mudchip-programatically
