MudBlazor MudChipSet - How to set selected MudChip programatically?
I'm using a couple of MudBlazors MudChip in a MudChipSet. The exact amount varies based on a the lenght of a list (creating on MudChip per object in that list).
Now I want to select one of these chips based on saved data. My approach was to create a List of MudChips with one per list item (only setting the "Text" property). I'm then filtering to get the one where "Text" is matching the string I have and set that result to the bind "selectedChip" variable.
However, that doesn't work. Any idea why?
See a demo here: try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOweEzaxfXjVrtFe

Two things:

You should not try to set the item on initialization but rather once the component has rendered. The ChipSet has a chance of being null when OnInitialized is being executed.
You are creating a brand new list of chips instead of using the chips that are rendered by your ChipSet foreach loop.

Changes:
    // Run this on first render to pre-set the selected chip
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) 
    {
        if (!firstRender) return; //exit if not first render

        selectedChip = availableChips.Single(e => e.Text == SelectedLocation);

        StateHasChanged();
    }

Add a reference to the chips that are being rendered
    @foreach (var entry in GetWorkLocationHoursMock())
    {
        <MudChip @ref=ChipRef Text="@entry.Location" Color="Color.Primary"/> 
    }

and add those items to your list, instead of creating new MudChip objects
    private MudChip ChipRef { set => availableChips.Add(value); }

The end result should look like this

Thanks a lot for the quick help! That does indeed work, but it won't work if the data source (in this case the variable "SelectedLocation") changes - like in this example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYQyEpEnqAyAJBDn
I would assume it should reflect that because it's using two way binding, right?

The binding is on selectedChip not selectedLocation so your method should be updating that. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQeaJkxKCFDBCfT

If you do want to use SelectedLocation so you only need to work with strings, you can do something like https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaGoazEHqszKHytp

Many thanks for your ongoing help, the second option worked perfectly!
Just in case anyone else comes across this: I moved updating the selectedChip to be a seperate function, as I had to handle various edge cases but wanted to keep the code readeable.
